# Success response even if email will be not delivered

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

For example, I have param `{{name}}` in my template. So, I have to pass this param in `TemplateData` of [`sendTemplatedEmail`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendTemplatedEmail.html) method.

But, if I don't, after sending request without this param I receive success response with `RequestId` and `MessageId`. And it looks like everything is fine. But it's not. This emails will be never delivered. They even aren't counted in Sending Statistics dashboard (https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-east-1#dashboard:).

Is it a bug? If this is the expected behavior, how can we handle such cases?

Comment: Have you reviewed this?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html  It may be considered a rendering failure.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yep. It could be the Rendering Failure. But, as mentioned in this doc, in this case it should be possible to see rejects on Sending Statistics page. But there are 0 rejects.

Comment: You should create the notification setup and verify that you don't get a reaction from the system through that mechanism.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've tried to setup email feedback forwarding. But even without that, as mentioned in aws console "if you don't configure a method of tracking bounces and complaints, Amazon SES will send bounce and complaint notifications to the email address in the Return-Path". `Return-Path` doesn't work, same for email notifications.

Comment: This isn't a bounce or a complaint -- it's a different failure mode.